# How to prove this material derivative formula rigoriously with experiment or prove it without the chain rule?

Tags: experimental-physics, continuum-mechanics

[image]

How to prove this rigoriously by experiment or prove it with other mechanics law but without the chain rule?

[image]

This is coming from reddy's introduction to continuum mechanics.

Also please explain what the above formula is term by term since i don't quite understand what this seem-to-be simple formula is.

Comment: Please use [MathJaX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset formulae instead of laughable small pictures of them. Also, please elaborate a bit more on your question: Where does the formula come form? What *exactly* do you not understand about it?

Comment: Looks like some kind of material derivative to me...

Comment: It is not an ok question. Not only does it completely ignore one of the site's formatting rules (i.e. type relevant equations, do not paste pictures of equations), but it's also hard to understand what is being asked. Furthermore, the question is un-motivated. *Why* do you not want to use the chain rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation in question is the convective derivative, used e.g. in the transport equation.

Its meaning in that context is "a box is moving downstream: the time-rate-of-change of stuff inside the box..." (with the other side of the equations saying "...is equal to the rate of stuff flowing into the box minus the rate flowing out, plus any intrinsic time-dependence of the stuff.")

To properly understand a box moving downstream we have to compute the following limit: $$\frac{{\rm D}f}{{\rm D}t} = \lim_{\delta t\to0} \frac{f(\vec r + \vec v~\delta t,~ t + \delta t) - f(\vec r,~ t)}{\delta t}.$$ In multivariable calculus you replace the tangent-lines of calculus with tangent-hyperplanes, so that the above term expands out to first order as: $$f(x + \delta x,~ y + \delta y,~ z + \delta z,~t+\delta t) \approx f(\vec r,~t) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}~\delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}~\delta y + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}~\delta z + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}~\delta t$$Therefore the above is, to first order in $\delta t$:$$\frac{{\rm D}f}{{\rm D}t} = \vec v\cdot\nabla f + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}.$$

Comment: Excuse me, what is other example except a box moving downstream

Comment: @Victor: Any conserved quantity in any sort of flow field has this sort of derivative in its transport equations. Concentrations of sugars in a flowing stream, the conserved x-coordinate of momentum of wind in the air, electric charge in a cosmic plasma.